# Sl 4, MVVM: When is the VM available for use by the View?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have a View and set its DataContext to the corresponding ViewModel.  In the Loaded event handler in the View code-behind, I want to set some Properties on the VM.  However, the View's DataContext is null at that point.
In the xaml:

```
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:PageViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the Loaded handler, page.xaml.cs:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  PageViewModel pvm = this.DataContext as PageViewModel;
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pvm is " + ((null == pvm) ? "null" : pvm.ToString()));
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the VM not available, yet, when the View fires the Loaded event?

UPDATE:  The real issue appears to be the VM is not getting hooked up to the View.  In UserControl_Loaded, pvm is null.
Currently, I am setting the DataContext on the root element of the layout; does it need to be set on the UserControl?  If so, how?

Thanks for any insight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:PageViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

by :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:PageViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to set the DC w/i the Resources, and that wasn't working, obviously...

Comment: didn't try, but you can probably use <UserControl DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
<UserControl.Resources>
<viewModels:PageViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>

Comment: I noticed that with my original xaml (setting the DC via StaticResource on the layout root) the Properties were correctly resolved in the Binding statement at design-time.  When I changed to your xaml, the Properties were not recognized.  I tried adding : d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:PageViewModel}"  to the layout root, but Properties in Binding statements still not recog. at design-time.  Thanks for your answers so far....